# how to reset input value in EJS with reset type button

Tags: node.js, ejs

i want to reset a input value when click 'reset' button.
i have a 1 select value, 3 input value type 'text'

```
<input type="submit" value="search" id="searchbtn" style="font-weight: bold;">
<input type="reset" value="reset" id="resetbtn" style="font-weight: bold;">
```

MSSQL is used to retrieve data from the server, and the input value outputs data as a query condition.

```
        <div id = "menues" class="menu" style="border-top: solid blue 3px">
              WareHouse  <select  id = "warehouse_id" name = "warehouse_id" >
                        <option value='*' selected>*</option>
                <% if (result2_data && Array.isArray(result2_data)) {
                    const uniqueValues = [];
                    result2_data.forEach(function(item) {
                      if (!uniqueValues.includes(item.wh_id)) {
                        uniqueValues.push(item.wh_id);
                      }
                    });
                    uniqueValues.forEach(function(value) { %>
                            <option value="<%=value%>" ><%=value%></option>
                        <% });
                  } %>
                    </select>&nbsp&nbsp
                    <script lang="js">
                        document.setting.warehouse_id.value = "<%=warehouse_id%>" || "*"; 
                    </script>
              PartId  <input type = "text" class="inputsize" name = "part_id" value = "<%=part_id%>" autocomplete="off">&nbsp&nbsp
             LOTNo <input type = "text" class = "inputsize" name = "lotno" value = "<%=lotno%>"  autocomplete="off">&nbsp&nbsp
              PartName  <input type="text" class="inputsize" name="part_name" value = "<%=part_name%>"  autocomplete="off">&nbsp&nbsp
                    <script lang="js">
                        
                    </script>
        </div>
```

All I want to do is get rid of the results searched through the reset button and make the search criteria blank, but in reality, only the search results disappear and the search conditions do not disappear.
and this is my event when click reset button

```
<script>
var reset = document.getElementById("resetbtn");
reset.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function removeAll() {
    var tmain = document.getElementById("tmain");
    var pagingul = document.getElementById("pagingul");
    tmain.remove();
    pagingul.remove();
  },
  false
);

reset.addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.setting.part_id.value = "";
  document.setting.lotno.value = "";
  document.setting.part_name.value = "";
});
</script>
```

Through `resetbtn`, all 3 input values are supposed to change into `''` or `null` (I just want a clear blank).

Comment: Does it work if you move the `.value = ""` codes inside the first `click` event?
Other than that, why is the `script` tag *empty* below the inputs for `part_id`, `lotno` and `part_name`(?); there must be some errors in the console when you click `resetbtn`? What is `setting` in this context?

Comment: @Aleksandar  Sorry, this is only a partial extraction of the total code and posted.
 `setting` is the ID of the foam that contains the search option and result code.
and yes, if i just tried with `document.setting.part_id.value = "" "` then it works.
i think my problem is come from my reset button. im gonna change <input> to <button> resetbtn. thank you a lot for your advice and help.
and also im sorry for my english skill.